# How to specify end-line characters for build_runner in flutter

Tags: flutter, serialization, mocking, code-generation

We are using generated mocks and JSON serialization in flutter. The command build_runner generating the necessary code always produces code with CRLF at the end. In git we store all files with LF as recommended and convert CRLF endings respectively on commit. This leads to misleading diffs for all files with every build_runner execution: When only one file has to be updated, it vanishes between tons of LF-CRLF updates.

How do you deal with this issue?

Is it possible to set the end-line character for the builder?

Comment: Is it generating files with CRLF endings on POSIX systems or on Windows?  If the former, that sounds like a bug.  If the latter, then I'd just make a build script or git precommit hook to automatically convert to Unix line endings.

Comment: I am working on Windows.
I think you'r suggestion is just what's happening and causing the problem: There's a conversion at commit time which changes CRLF to LF each time i generate files. Those files checked out later from git differ from generated ones with same name with only differences line ending
Question is: how can I force the generator to create the LF endings (instead of CRLF)?

Comment: I doubt that there's any way to control the line-endings.  In general, code-generation tools generate text files, and text operations use the platform's native line endings.  Why are you even storing generated code in git at all?

Comment: @jamesdlin because you can start a project without generating any code on another machine

Comment: @Nordmeyer could you find any solution?